# VB.NET Keybord tracker

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

Hello I have a VB NET application and I would like to add it a keybord key pressed catching system so I can track any keybord key that is pressed on any application that is running on my computer and uses keybord.
If someone has any idea thanks for sharing it.
I Hope my question was clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a Global KeyBoard hook, look at this [`CodePlex Project`](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/). It will allow you to intercept the Global Keyboard events.

From Link:

> This library allows you to tap keyboard and mouse and to detect and
>   record their activity even when an application is inactive and runs in
>   background.
>
> This library attaches to windows global hooks, tracks keyboard and
>   mouse clicks and movement and raises common .NET events with
>   KeyEventArgs and MouseEventArgs, so you can easily retrieve any
>   information you need:

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer, seems a promising library.          I have another question and sorry please do you know a way to capture keybord key pressed but not char by char but catching the whole word typed by the user (for a string comparaison porpuse) this link will explain better what I mean :[link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgoDzkboT0A) and thank you so much.

Comment: @user1818439 Not with the .Net Framework, You are limited to Keyboard and Mouse Hooks. You would need to find the Handle of the EditControl that was being typed in and use WinApi Functions to get the Content of it.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer, if you have some links for guiding me I will apreciate, otherwise thank you so much for you very helpful answers. Thanks again.